# Javascript Filter With Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter

I am trying to use checkboxes to filter page content. I got it to hide content when I check the box, but it does not show all content again when unchecked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').change(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        var checked;
        if (checked = $(this).attr('checked'));
        var reclessons = $('li[data-rec='+$(this).data('rec')+']');
        checked ?  reclessons.show('slow'): reclessons.hide('slow');
    });
    var unchecked=0;
    if(unchecked=0){$('li').show('slow');}
});
});
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, give the filtering checkboxes their own class and select them by that instead of selecting all inputs.

Comment: Neither of your `if` statements have `==`

Comment: The first is short hand, the second is a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.attr()` method doesn't return a boolean value, also `=` is assignment, you don't compare the values, you should use `==` or `===` operator for comparison.

```
var $ch = $('input[type=checkbox]');
$ch.change(function() {
    // show/hide the related `li` element
    $('li[data-rec='+$(this).data('rec')+']').toggle(this.checked);
    // show all `li` elements if there is no checked checkbox 
    if ( $ch.filter(':checked').length === 0 ) {
       $('li').show();
    } 
});
```

Comment: you should really use `.prop("checked")`

Comment: @stevemarvell Why? `.prop('checked')` returns value of the `.checked` property i.e `this.checked`. There is no difference.

Comment: But for the fact that `.prop()` is made for the job and `.checked` is an undocumented feature.

Comment: @stevemarvell Actually `.prop()` doesn't belong to any standard. It's just a (_helper_) method of the jQuery object, http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-checked

Comment: Lots of what are being used are documented helper functions.

Comment: @stevemarvell Yes, I meant to, jQuery is a _library_, a helper library. In comparison `checked` is a property of DOM, a standard. `prop()` reads standard DOM HTMLElement object's **prop** erties.

Comment: I accept your argument but still support the use of documented accessors.

Comment: I am, however, stealing your use of `toggle`

Answer (score 1):

This is the basis for what you want. Note the `prop` for checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemarvell/kEkdy/

```
<input type="checkbox" data-target="thing1" checked="1"/>
<div id="thing1">Thing 1</div>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="thing2" checked="1"/>
<div id="thing2">Thing 2</div>
```

With this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox][data-target]').change(function() {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('#' + target).toggle(checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used cuisines for my checkbox items. The following code snippet gives the logic for checkboxes filtering. `handleCuisineChange` is the function that contains the logic. The length of `for` loop is 8 since the number of cuisines (the number of checkbox items) I have taken here is 8. Replace the `cuisines` here with your checkbox data. Apply this logic and your checkbox items are ready for filtering.

Inside `axios` I used my own backend API `getCuisine` and port number `7000`.

```html
handleCuisineChange=(cuisine_id)=>
    {
        const {cuisineArray}=this.state; //an empty array declared in constructor
       
        if (cuisineArray.indexOf(cuisine_id) == -1)
        {
            cuisineArray.push(cuisine_id);
        }
        else
        {
            var index=cuisineArray.indexOf(cuisine_id);
            cuisineArray.splice(index,1);
        }    

        const {cuisineArray2}=this.state; //an empty array declared in constructor
        let i=0;
        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if(cuisineArray[i]==undefined)
            {
                cuisineArray2[i]=cuisineArray[0];
            }
            else
            {
                cuisineArray2[i]=cuisineArray[i];
            }
        }

        this.props.history.push(`/checking3?cuisine_id1=${cuisineArray2[0]}&cuisine_id2=${cuisineArray2[1]}&cuisine_id3=${cuisineArray2[2]}&cuisine_id4=${cuisineArray2[3]}&cuisine_id5=${cuisineArray2[4]}&cuisine_id6=${cuisineArray2[5]}&cuisine_id7=${cuisineArray2[6]}&cuisine_id8=${cuisineArray2[7]}`);
        let filterObj={cuisine_id1:cuisineArray2[0],cuisine_id2:cuisineArray2[1],cuisine_id3:cuisineArray2[2],cuisine_id4:cuisineArray2[3],cuisine_id5:cuisineArray2[4],cuisine_id6:cuisineArray2[5],cuisine_id7:cuisineArray2[6],cuisine_id8:cuisineArray2[7]};
        axios(
            {
                method:'POST',
                url:`http://localhost:7000/getCuisine`,
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                data:filterObj
            }
        )
        .then(res=>
            {
                this.setState({restaurants:res.data.restaurants});
            })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }

render()
    {
        const {restaurants}=this.state;
        return(
            
                <div>
                   
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"1"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > North Indian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines"  id={"2"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("2")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > south indian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"3"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("3")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > chinese </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"4"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > fast food </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"5"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Street food </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"6"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > American </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"7"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Italian </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisines" id={"8"} onChange={(event) => this.handleCuisineChange("1")}  />
                            <span className="checkbox-items" > Mexican </span> <div style={{display: "block"}}> </div>
                </div>
       )
  } //render end
```